# Readdir function for MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to convert a program from Octave to MATLAB, the problem is that the original code uses some functions from Octave and I'm trying to find the equivalent or a similar way to move around the problem.

I need to get a list of files in order to work.

Example:

```
fileslist = readdir('./input');
for i=1:length(fileslist)
  string = fileslist{i};
  fprintf('  file %3i: %s\n',i, string); 
end
fprintf('--------------\n\n');
```

Comment: the functions `dir` and `ls` work similarly. you may need to split to string yourself via `strsplit` etc.

Answer (score 3):

The functions [`ls`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html) and [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) are the closest equivalents to [`readdir`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/readdir.html). You'll have to format their outputs slightly to get them into the same output format as `readdir` (i.e. a cell array of folder contents):

### For `ls` (on Windows):

```
fileslist = cellstr(ls('./input'));
```

### For `ls` (on UNIX):

```
fileslist = strsplit(ls('./input')).';
```

### For `dir`:

```
fileslist = dir('./input');
fileslist = {fileslist.name}.';
```

Comment: Wait a sec, the doc says that *`readdir`returns the names of files in the directory.* Wouldn't `ls` and `dir`  be returning the names of files  ?

Comment: furthermore, I'm not sure about `dir`, but it is worth noting that the output of `ls` is partly system dependent. Also `ls -w` maybe required to prevent 'clumping' of filenames.

Comment: @SardarUsama: The `readdir` documentation says it returns *files*, but when I tested it it returns both files and folders.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: I think I addressed the system dependence, but I'm not sure what you mean by "clumping". Is that related to the sorting of the names?

Comment: @gnovice actually, my bad, what I really had in mind wasn't a linux vs windows thing, it was an octave vs matlab. I just got confused. I just remember a recent incident where I discovered `ls` works differently on octave compared to matlab (matlab doesn't separate the names with a newline, and you have to split in a different way). This may or may not be of interest to the OP, depending on whether octave-matlab cross-compatibility is an issue or not. In any case, `dir` is probably more reliable in this case.

Comment: About `ls`, it actually depends on the _shell_ you've set (`bash` by default, but possibly `zsh`, `fish` or others). See more [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/312837-change-shell-used-by-matlab).

Answer (score 0):

As @Tasos mentions, there is [`dir`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html).
However if you look on File Exchange there are some more powerful ones that I highly recommend. In particular I suggest taking a look at [`subdir`](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15859-subdir--a-recursive-file-search), and possibly in combination with [`natsort`](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47434-natural-order-filename-sort) if you need to load files/folders with numbered names.

Comment: Yes, later on the code I need to choose and load one of the files in the input folder, the original code uses the function source, I tried with load from matlab, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I'm... really not sure if this was a question : \ Let me try to paraphrase: you tried subdir, but then couldn't load the actual file using `load`? If you're still trying, if you're more specific I can maybe give some suggestions. If you've gotten an alternative working already and don't need this, then that's great : ). `subdir` doesn't really do anything that you can't do with `dir`, it's just wrapped up nicely so you don't have to code a lot of things yourself (like looping through subdirectories). If you don't need it though, it's always nice to not need extra dependencies.